# What is the best method to write multiple records to excel in a dynamic way?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, export-to-excel

I am testing an ERP Application using selenium webdriver.i need to write the result to excel sheet.For each step now i am writing seperate code to write to excel. there are 7 main modules and in each main module 10 sub modules which increaces the codesize when i write a code for each step validation.
my current code:-

```
Label col12row9 = new Label(12,j,arlogin[3],getCellFormatnormal(redFont));
ws.addCell(col12row9);
Label col0row9 = new Label(0, j,"ReqSmok"+i);
ws.addCell(col0row9);
Label col1row9 = new Label(1, j,"Browser Details");
Range col1row9r = ws.mergeCells(1,j, 5, j); 
ws.addCell(col1row9);
Label col6row9 = new Label(6,j,"Get the Browser name ");
Range col2row9r = ws.mergeCells(6,j, 11, j);    
ws.addCell(col6row9);
```

For each entry
I am looking for some methos where i can pass all the six values each time and it will write to excel

My expected code is something like this:-

```
private void ResulttoExcellabel(String[] ResulttoExcellabel)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException, WriteException {

    WritableSheet sheet1 = null;
    FileOutputStream f1 = new FileOutputStream(
            "D:\\smoketest_AIM.xls");
    WritableWorkbook wwb = Workbook.createWorkbook(f1);
    sheet1 = wwb.createSheet("result", 0);
    Label l = new Label(1,7,"a[0]");sheet1.addCell(l);
    Label l1 = new Label(1,7,"a[1]");sheet1.addCell(l1);
    Label l2 = new Label(1,7,"a[2]");sheet1.addCell(l2);
    Label l3 = new Label(1,7,"a[3]");sheet1.addCell(l3);
    Label l4 = new Label(1,7,"a[4]");sheet1.addCell(l4);
    Label l5 = new Label(1,7,"a[5]");sheet1.addCell(l5);
    Label l6 = new Label(1,7,"a[6]");sheet1.addCell(l6);
```

}
and to call this at every step like this:- ResulttoExcellabel(ResulttoExcellabelr); -
this should pass all the values to that method and then it should be written to excel sheet and 
workbook.write performed at the end of the test.
Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i worked out a solution for this 
1) get all results to a list/string

2)using for loop for string array (mine was 2 dimentional say,result[x][y])
3)again looped with i and j for cols and rows in excel and wrote my results

Answer (score 0):

```
                for(y=9;y<arraynoofrows+9;y++)
                {
                    testcaseid=testcaseid+1;    
                    String testcaseid1 = String.valueOf(testcaseid);
                    col=0;
                    for(j=0;j<6;j++)
                    {
                        colnum=TestResultcolnumbers[col];
                        Label l = new Label(colnum,y,ar[y-9][j]);ws.addCell(l);
                        System.out.println("value of colnum"+colnum+" value of row number"+y+" value of i "+y+" value of j"+colnum+"value of ar[i][j] "+ar[y-9][j]);
                        col=col+1;
                        System.out.println(colnum);
                    }
                }
```